# Elixir high order function

Tags: elixir

I wrote the following simple model:

```
defmodule Simple do
  def add(a, b) do a + b end
  som = fn(x, y) -> x + y end
  def oper_array(fct, arr, init) do
    Enum.scan(arr, init, fct.())
  end
end
```

But

```
Simple.oper_array(a, 0, Simple.som) or 
Simple.oper_array(a, 0, Simple.add)
```

always give

```
(UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function Simple.som/0 or
(UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function Simple.add/0
```

Same result if I write the function 'oper_array' like that:

```
Enum.scan(arr, init, fct)
```

How should I write the function 'oper_array' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by defining the module without the anonymous function.

```
defmodule Simple do
  def add(a, b), do: a + b
  def oper_array(fct, arr, init) do
    Enum.scan(arr, init, fct)
  end
end
```

#### 1. `Simple.oper_array(a, 0, Simple.som)`

Issues:

1. The order of the elements in the function is incorrect.
2. The `&` operator is not required because it is already an anonymous function expression available in the context which is the case below. *(I think)*
3. The `som/2` function was declared as an anonymous function inside the module so it is not a function that is publicly available and hence cannot be used outside the context in which it was defined.

This should work:

```
a = [1,2,3]
Simple.oper_array(fn(x, y) -> x + y end, a, 0)
```

or

```
a = [1,2,3]
som = fn(x, y) -> x + y end
Simple.oper_array(som, a, 0)
```

### 2. `Simple.oper_array(a, 0, Simple.add)`

Issues:

1. The order of the elements in the function is incorrect.
2. The function should include the arity.
3. The `&` operator should be added before the function name to evaluate it to a function. *(I think)*

This should work:

```
a = [1,2,3]
Simple.oper_array(&Simple.add/2, a, 0)
```

Comment: `a = [1,2,3]`
`Simple.oper_array(&Simple.add/2, a, 0)` works but not with the anonymous function `som = fn(x, y) -> x + y end`. The order of the elements was incorrect... yes sorry for that. I thank you very much.